# Tree-Based Graph Visualization Tool

Tags: data-visualization, graphs

I'm looking for tools that support tree-based visualization of graphs. This video has an example but I can't find the tool online.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwlybZkF6lo

Here's another paper describing a more advanced implementation but I can't find that tool either.

https://vdl.sci.utah.edu/publications/2018_infovis_juniper/

Any ideas?

Comment: This mostly looks like a mindmap to me. Are you sure you don't need a mind map?

Answer (score 0):

On Power BI you can find many of those like [Tree](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA200000621?tab=Overview).

Power BI has a [marketplace](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi-visuals) and you can download visuals for free. You can then share them or embed in your website.